# Creating daylight savings-aware DateTime when server set to UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, utc, dst

My application is hosted on Windows Azure, which has all servers set to UTC.

I need to know when any given `DateTime` is subject to daylight savings time. For simplicity, we can assume that my users are all in the UK (so using Greenwich Mean Time).

The code I am using to convert my `DateTime` objects is

```
public static DateTime UtcToUserTimeZone(DateTime dateTime)
{
    dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Greenwich Standard Time");

    var userDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, timeZone);

    return DateTime.SpecifyKind(userDateTime, DateTimeKind.Local);
}
```

However, the following test fails at the last line; the converted `DateTime` does not know that it should be in daylight savings time.

```
[Test]
public void UtcToUserTimeZoneShouldWork()
{
    var utcDateTime = new DateTime(2014, 6, 1, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    Assert.IsFalse(utcDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime());

    var dateTime = Utils.UtcToUserTimeZone(utcDateTime);
    Assert.IsTrue(dateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime());
}
```

Note that this only fails when my Windows time zone is set to **(UTC) Co-ordinated Universal Time**. When it is set to **(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London** (or any other northern-hemisphere time zone that observes daylight savings), the test passes. If you change this setting in Windows a restart of Visual Studio is required in order for the change to fully take effect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The main thing you are missing is that "Greenwich Standard Time" is *not* the `TimeZoneInfo` id for London.  That one actually belongs to "(UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik".

  You want "GMT Standard Time", which maps to "(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"

  Yes, Windows time zones are weird.  (At least you don't live in France, which gets strangely labeled as "Romance Standard Time"!)
- Also, you should *not* be doing this part:

  ```
  return DateTime.SpecifyKind(userDateTime, DateTimeKind.Local);
  ```

  That will make various other code think it came from the local machine's time zone.  Leave it with the "Unspecified" kind.  (Or even better, use a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`)
- Then you also need to use the `.IsDaylightSavingsTime` method on the `TimeZoneInfo` object, rather than the one on the `.DateTime` object.  (There are *two* different methods, with the same name, on different objects, with differing behavior.  Ouch!)

But I wholeheartedly agree that this is way too complicated and error prone.  Just use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org). You'll be glad you did!

Comment: For now, using the `.IsDaylightSavingsTime` method on `TimeZoneInfo` is going to meet my requirements, many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your last line specifies that the value is in the local time zone of the system it's running in - but it's not really... it's converted using a different time zone.

Basically `DateTime` is [somewhat broken](http://noda-time.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), in my view - which makes it hard to use correctly. There's no way of saying "This `DateTime` value is in time zone x" - you can perform a conversion to find a specific local time, but that doesn't remember the time zone.

For example, from the docs of [`DateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> This method determines whether the current DateTime value falls within the daylight saving time range of the **local time zone**, which is returned by the TimeZoneInfo.Local property.

Obviously I'm biased, but I'd recommend using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project for this instead - quite possibly using a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime.htm). You can call [`GetZoneInterval`](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime_GetZoneInterval.htm) to obtain the [`ZoneInterval`](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_TimeZones_ZoneInterval.htm) for that `ZonedDateTime`, and then use [`ZoneInterval.Savings`](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/api/html/P_NodaTime_TimeZones_ZoneInterval_Savings.htm) to check whether the current offset contains a daylight savings component:

```
bool daylight = zonedDateTime.GetZoneInterval().Savings != Offset.Zero;
```

This is slightly long-winded... I've added a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=264) to consider adding an `IsDaylightSavingTime()` method to `ZonedDateTime` as well...

Comment: @MattJohnson: Well it's not part of the core library at the moment - but it possibly should be. Until then, the extension method certainly works...

Comment: Thanks Jon, I had wondered if this was going to be a good occasion to try out NodaTime. It looks like Matt's suggestion is going to resolve this issue for me though.

Comment: @RichardEv: Well, I would think of this as just another indication of why the BCL types (and time zone IDs!) are a pain to work with. Go on, try Noda Time... you know you want to :)

Comment: Well alright then, I will add *rework codebase to use Noda Time* to my backlog. ;-)